# .NET Core / JQuery.Load with parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-core, razor

So, I have a .NET Core 3.1 Pages application and I need to call a PageModel function in a Razor Page from a call to jQuery.Load. It works with no parameters (see below):

```
$("#divSubComp").load('/Selections/Create?handler=SubCompsPartial', function () {});
```

// successfully calls …

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetSubCompsPartial()
// breakpoint hit
```

However, I need to pass a parameter to OnGetSubCompsPartial and I can't get the syntax right. I currently have the below:

```
$("#divSubComp").load('/Selections/Create?handler=SubCompsPartial', { id: $(this).id }, function () {});
```

// and …

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetSubCompsPartial(string id)
```

It doesn't reach OnGetSubCompsPartial. I'm getting error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 () [https://localhost:44323/Selections/Create?handler=SubCompsPartial]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use the browser developer network tab to determine the exact url that's being sent and try that manually. eg it might be `/create?handler=sub?id=123` or `/create?handler=sub/?id=123` alternatively, move the `handler=` part into the parameters so all parameters are in one place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the id as a parameter to the url you are loading:

```
$("#divSubComp").load('/Selections/Create?handler=SubCompsPartial&id=' + $(this).id, function () {});
```

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Got it working. The only point of note is I had to remove the '$' before (this).id. The id value was 'undefined' with '$' but had the correct value without?